# Having an issue with pandas df.replace

Tags: python, csv, pandas, replace

The gist is that I need to write a database sorting program, and most of it works, but here's a little niggle; for the last part it needs to be sorted out as an average but the problem is that my CSV file isn't delimited so it looks something like this:

```
     name             name1         score1  score2 score3 
0    ['Harry'        'Potter'       9       10     8]      
1    ['Scrooge'      'McDuck'       7       5      6]
2    ['Shovel'       'Knight'       4       2      3]
```

I need the program to sort out the scores from highest to lowest as one of the possible options, however, the presence of ] in the column causes issues, so I attempted this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
print('Sorted scores')
scores3 = df['score3']
scores3 = scores3.replace(']', '')
scores = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']].values
a = np.array(df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']])
b = a.astype(int)
a.sort(axis=1)
df['score1'], df['score2'], df['score3'] = a.T
print(df)
```

And I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python code\Task 3 pandas testing 12.py", line 69, in <module>
    b = a.astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 8]'
```

So my attempt to remove the ']' is not working, and I'm not quite sure why. Anyone know why it's not working properly?

EDIT: @Anand S Kumar, your solution works but it's not quite what I wanted.
I need the data to be sorted out horizontally in rows, not vertically, so the end result should look like this

```
     name             name1         score1  score2 score3 
0    ['Harry'        'Potter'       10      9      8]      
1    ['Scrooge'      'McDuck'       7       6      5]
2    ['Shovel'       'Knight'       4       3      2]
```

Normally a CSV file used for database purposes looks like this:

```
name   name1  score1  score2 score3 
Harry, Potter, 10,      8,      9
```

However due to the fact that the results are not delimited, they have the [] and the '' for the first two columns.

I was told that df.sort doesn't mix up values from different columns, so I was hypothesising that if I cannot change the values of the actual columns, then I could have a shot at making another column with the values sorted highest to lowest, like this:

```
     name             name1         score1  score2 score3  highestscoretolowestscore
0    ['Harry'        'Potter'       9       10     8]      10 9 8
1    ['Scrooge'      'McDuck'       7       5      6]      7 6 5
2    ['Shovel'       'Knight'       4       2      3]      4 3 2
```

I added this bit to the program:

```
df['highestscoretolowestscore'] = df.sort(['score1','score2','score3'], ascending=False, inplace=True, axis=0)
```

However it results in this occuring:

```
           name     name1  score1  score2  score3 highestscoretolowestscore
0     ['Atticus'   'Finch'       9      10       8                      None
1         ['Jem'   'Finch'       7       5       6                      None
2  ['Jean Louise   'Finch'       4       2       3                      None
```

So I think there's an issue with the dataframe assignment but I'm unsure as how to remedy it.

Comment: What does your csv look like?

Comment: Try `scores3 = scores3.str.replace(']', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure how your csv looks like, there could be a better way to do this based on how the csv looks. But basically your issue is that when you do-

```
scores3 = scores3.replace(']', '')
```

You just point scores3 to a new series, this does not change anything in your original DataFrame.

You would need to do -

```
df = pd.read_csv('classa.csv')
print('Sorted scores')
df['score3'] = df['score3'].str.replace(']', '')
df['score3'] = df['score3'].astype(int)
df = df.sort(['score1', 'score2', 'score3'], ascending=False)
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
         name     name1  score1  score2 score3
0    ['Harry'  'Potter'       9      10     8]
1  ['Scrooge'  'McDuck'       7       5     6]
2   ['Shovel'  'Knight'       4       2     3]

In [83]: print('Sorted scores')
Sorted scores

In [84]: df['score3'] = df['score3'].str.replace(']', '')

In [85]: df['score3'] = df['score3'].astype(int)

In [86]: df = df.sort(['score1', 'score2', 'score3'], ascending=False)

In [87]: df
Out[87]:
         name     name1  score1  score2  score3
0    ['Harry'  'Potter'       9      10       8
1  ['Scrooge'  'McDuck'       7       5       6
2   ['Shovel'  'Knight'       4       2       3
```

---

For what you want (sorting in the rows) , you can do (very similar to your own method) -

```
df['score3'] = df['score3'].str.replace(']', '')
df['score3'] = df['score3'].astype(int)
a = np.array(df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3']])
a = a.astype(int)
a.sort(axis=1)
df['score1'], df['score2'], df['score3'] = a.T[::-1,:]
```

Comment: Updated the code, still have something funny with dataframe assignment. @Anand S Kumar